# Remove indices from object of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const obj = {
  0: {
    name: 'item1',
    slug: 'slug1',
    price: 64,
    featured_image: null,
    onSale: undefined,
    // ...
  },
  1: {
   name: 'item2',
    slug: 'slug2',
    price: 64,
    featured_image: null,
    onSale: undefined,
    // ...
  },
  2: {
      name: 'item3',
    slug: 'slug3',
    price: 64,
    featured_image: null,
    onSale: undefined,
    // ...
  }
};
```

Result I expect:

const obj = [
{
name: 'item1',
slug: 'slug1',
price: 64,
featured_image: null,
onSale: undefined,
},
{
name: 'item2',
slug: 'slug2',
price: 64,
featured_image: null,
onSale: undefined,
},
{
name: 'item3',
slug: 'slug3',
price: 64,
featured_image: null,
onSale: undefined,
}
]

I cannot get ride of the index of each element of the array in order to map the function properly, any help would be appreaciate it.

i tried with Object.values but still

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: what you have is an object with key value pairs. keys are the indices. why not Object.values. you can map over Object.values

Comment: Please be careful of terminology. `obj` is a JS object, not JSON

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Is this even JavaScript? `st obj = ` is a syntax error in JavaScript. Did you miss out the first three letters of `const`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thats probably it

Comment: You could use ```Object.entries(your_object)```.

Comment: How does `Object.values(obj)` not work?

Answer (score 0):

You have an object of objects with each key an index. It sounds as if you want an array of objects relating to the values of the incoming object.

```
Array.from(Object.values(obj))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Comment: `Array.from` does absolutely nothing here. `Object.values` already returns an array.